# How do I use j2objc to convert my android app to ios?

Tags: android, j2objc

I have been searching for the past days on a tutorial on how to use https://developers.google.com/j2objc/guides/getting-started to convert my Android App (I have the source code) to IOS and I have found nothing.

If I try to convert individual .java files in my project, I get this error:

```
 error: cannot find symbol
```

in every single file. Obviously, what I have been doing is wrong.

How do I use it?

Thank you

Comment: For converting parts of your app, [Doppl](http://doppl.co/) wraps around `j2objc` and is designed for Android app conversion. However, neither `j2objc` nor Doppl convert Android apps to iOS. They convert certain classes from Java to Objective-C. Pure Java code -- things without references to Android classes -- usually convert fairly well, but the more tightly coupled your code is to Android, the less likely it is that these tools will be useful to you.

Comment: @CommonsWare thank you for your answer. I will check Doppl and hopefully it will work for me.